# Copy timecode from SEI Picture Timing to MXF Timecode Stream with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, timecode, h.265, hevc

I am receiving an HEVC encoded live stream that contains SMPTE 12-1 timecode in the SEI picture timing, as it is recommended in  [**ITU-T Rec-H.265-202108 Annex D.3.3 Picture timing SEI message semantics**](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.265-202108-I/en). I want to copy this timecode to a new timecode stream in an MXF Container, according to [**EBU – Recommendation R 122**](https://tech.ebu.ch/publications/r122).

I can use the command `ffprobe -i input.ts -show_frames` to see the timecode information of each frame in a recording of such a stream:

```
TAG:timecode=09:06:19:01
[SIDE_DATA]
side_data_type=SMPTE 12-1 timecode
[TIMECODE]
value=09:06:19:01
[/TIMECODE]
[/SIDE_DATA]
```

But I have not found any way to access the SEI messages with FFmpeg. I already did a lot of research and tried playing around with things like:
`-copytb 1`, `-timecode 00:00:00:00` or `-map_metadata 0:s:0` without any luck. The only thing about SEI that I could find in the FFmpeg docs is the [`sei_user_data`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#toc-h264_005fmetadata), which is only used for insertion.

Is there any way to achieve this with FFmpeg and without writing C/C++ (or any other) code around libav*?